# Prevent SVG from inflating DIV in height

Tags: html, css, svg

On my page I want to fit SVG into the container frame. Everything works well in width. But when the height exceeds, the page begins to grow and scrolling appears (big red).
[image: problem]

How to limit the height growth so that the picture always fits into the container??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .full {
            background-color: cadetblue;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            border: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 225);
        }

        .top {
            background-color: brown;
            color: white;
            height: 20vh;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }

        .bottom {
            display: flex;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .left {
            background-color: rgb(70, 124, 168);
            width: 400px;
            border: 5px solid rgb(20, 255, 36);
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }

        .right {
            background-color: rgb(255, 140, 0);
            color: white;
            /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
            border: 5px solid rgb(20, 224, 255);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="full">FULL
        <div class="top">
            TOP
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="left">LEFT</div>
            <div class="right">

                <svg class="scaling-svg" width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
                    <rect fill="#FF0000" height="296" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" width="296" x="2" y="2" />
                </svg>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything works out well in width, and I want the same behavior in height.
[image]

Comment: So like this? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rNPmqOE

Answer (score 0):

If the SVG is not allowed to overflow one option could be to set the [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute on the SVG element:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.full {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 225);
}

.top {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  height: 20vh;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left {
  background-color: rgb(70, 124, 168);
  width: 400px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(20, 255, 36);
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.right {
  background-color: rgb(255, 140, 0);
  color: white;
  /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
  border: 5px solid rgb(20, 224, 255);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">FULL
  <div class="top">
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>
    <div class="right">
      <svg class="scaling-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect fill="#FF0000" height="296" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" width="296" x="2" y="2" />
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="150" fill="gray" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Another option is to remove the `viewBox` attribute and place the the content of the SVG according to the contect of the SVG:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.full {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 225);
}

.top {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  height: 20vh;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left {
  background-color: rgb(70, 124, 168);
  width: 400px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(20, 255, 36);
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.right {
  background-color: rgb(255, 140, 0);
  color: white;
  /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
  border: 5px solid rgb(20, 224, 255);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">FULL
  <div class="top">
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>
    <div class="right">
      <svg class="scaling-svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <rect fill="#FF0000" height="98%" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" width="98%" x="1%" y="1%" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="120px" fill="gray" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. I would like to not distort the image, but just fit it into the frame.